# Can't download large file from Google Drive as one single folder, always splits into multiple parts

Tags: google-drive, download

I was able to download a file (over 70GB when already uploaded as a zip file) with no problems 6 months ago but now it splits everything into multiple zip files? Why is this?

Answer (score 16):

You can also use Google's Takeout system for downloading one large folder from Google Drive. It allows up to 50GB .zip files.

Here are the main steps:

1. In Google Drive temporarily move the folder you want to download to the top level of your drive (the "My Drive" folder).
2. Go to https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout
3. On **Step 1: Select data to include** deselect all except for Drive. Then click the "All Drive Selected" button
   [image]
4. Uncheck "Include all files and folders in Drive", select the one folder you want. Then proceed to the next step
   [image]
5. Under "File type & size" be sure to change the folder size to 50GB.
   [image]
6. Confirm and wait for the download link via email
   [image]

Notes:

- This assumes you are the owner of the files.
- Don't forget to move your folder back to it's original location afterwards

Comment: I know it's not the question asked, but a tip: If you have tools to extract tar.gz files (if on linux you probably do), they in many cases have a slightly better compression ratio compared to zip.

Answer (score 3):

Chunk zipping is a new Google Drive standard for downloading a large bundle of files (or single file) from the internet. You can try this tutorial on how to download a file from Google Drive using the command line API:

**1.** **Get the file ID:**

- go to your [**Google Drive**](https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive)
- right-click the file you want to download
- click on **Get shareable link**
- link looks like this: **`https://drive.google.com/open?id=xxx`** where **`xxx`** is the ID you will need after few more steps

**2.** **Get an OAuth token:**

- go to **[OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)**
- under **Select the Scope** box, scroll down to **Drive API v3**
- expand it and select **`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`**
- click on the blue **<kbd>Authorize APIs</kbd>** button
- login if you are prompted
- and then click on **Exchange authorization code for tokens** to get a token
- copy the **Access token** for further use

**3.** **Download the file:**

- if you are on Windows open up the PowerShell and run this command:


  ```
  Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/xxx?alt=media 
                    -Method Get 
                    -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer ttt"} 
                    -OutFile zzz
  ```

  - where **`xxx`** = file ID
  - **`ttt`** is Access token
  - and **`zzz`** is output file (Avatar.mkv)
- if you are on OS X or Linux open up the Terminal and run this command:


  ```
  curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ttt" https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/xxx?alt=media 
       -o zzz
  ```

Comment: Does this work for folders?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to using the APIs, install Backup & Sync and download your file that way - it's simpler.

Comment: This tool does not download a large file. Start over again and again.